# when to pass values such as 'none' to function in python pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a doubt in a function called read_excel(), here is a parameter called sheetnames and I have a doubt when should we pass 'none' to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you can pass `None` for

> Pass a None to return a dictionary of all available sheets.

check [Specifying Sheets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-sheets):

```
# Returns a dictionary of DataFrames
df = read_excel('path_to_file.xls',sheet_name=None)
```

But if pass string `none` it read sheet name called `none`:

```
df = read_excel('path_to_file.xls',sheet_name='none')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was helpfull..:-)